# The time of execution doesn't change whether I increase the number of threads or not

Tags: openmp, execution-time

I am executing the following code snippet as explained in the openMP tutorial. But what I see is the time of execution doesn't change with NUM_THREADS, infact, the time of execution just keeps changing a lot..I am wondering if the way I am trying to measure the time is wrong. I tried using clock_gettime, but I see the same results. Can any one help on this please. More than the problem of reduction in time with use of openMP, I am troubled why the time reported varies a lot.

```
#include "iostream"
#include "omp.h"
#include "stdio.h"
double getTimeNow();
static long num_steps = 10000000;
#define PAD 8
#define NUM_THREADS 1

int main ()
{ 

int i,nthreads;
double pi, sum[NUM_THREADS][PAD];
double t0,t1;

double step = 1.0/(double) num_steps;
t0 = omp_get_wtime();
#pragma omp_set_num_threads(NUM_THREADS);
#pragma omp parallel 
{
    int i, id,nthrds;
    double x;
    id = omp_get_thread_num();
    nthrds = omp_get_num_threads();
    if(id==0) nthreads = nthrds;
    for (i=id,sum[id][0]=0;i< num_steps; i=i+nthrds)
    {

     x = (i+0.5)*step;
         sum[id][0] += 4.0/(1.0+x*x);
    }
}
for(i=0, pi=0.0;i<nthreads;i++)pi += sum[i][0] * step;


t1 = omp_get_wtime();
printf("\n value obtained is %f\n",pi);
std::cout << "It took "
              << t1-t0
              << " seconds\n";

return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you compile this example? Do you use special flag for OpenMP (-fopenmp for gcc, -openmp for icc, etc.)?

Comment: Yes, I 've added the flag  -fopenmp in this case.

Comment: omp_set_num_threads is a function, not a compiler directive. You should remove #pragma before it.

Comment: Thank you very much Andrey, I can now see a good difference in the execution time. I don't know how accept your comment as an answer. But you definitely helped me to find the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `openmp_set_num_threads()`, but it is a function, not a compiler directive. You should use it without `#pragma`:

```
openmp_set_num_threads(NUM_THREADS);
```

Also, you can set the number of threads in the compiler directive, but the keyword is different:

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
```

The preferred way is not to hardcode the number of threads in your program, but use the environment variable OMP_NUM_THREADS. For example, in bash:

```
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4
```

However, the last example is not suited for your program.